# Move every file of every folder to another folder

Tags: applescript

I am looking to write an AppleScript to move every file in every folder to another folder.

Currently, this is what I have:

```
tell application "Finder"
    move (get every file of every folder of folder "Source_Folder" of desktop) to folder "Destination_Folder" of desktop
end tell
```

But this throws an error saying: `error "Finder got an error: Can’t get document file \"ALGE71FL.cpg\" of folder \"Destination_Folder\" of folder \"Desktop\" of folder \"THIS_USER\" of folder \"Users\" of startup disk." number -1728 from document file "ALGE71FL.cpg" of folder "Destination_Folder" of folder "Desktop" of folder "THIS_USER" of folder "Users" of startup disk`

Where `ALGE71FL.cpg` is the first file of interest.

Any solutions to this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to move only the files in the folders and not the folders themselves.  This following AppleScript code is one way to achieve your goal.

```
activate
set searchFolder to choose folder with prompt "Choose The Folder To Search"

activate
set destinationFolder to choose folder with prompt "Choose The Folder To Move Files To"

tell application "Finder"
    set theFiles to (files of entire contents of searchFolder) as alias list
    move theFiles to destinationFolder
end tell
```